# Python Substring Regex Extraction

Tags: python, date, substring, extract

I have the following types of strings:
`FWI20010112`
`DC20030405` etc...

I need to extract segments of the strings into separate variables like this (example):

**name**: FWI

**year**: 2001

**month**: 01

**day**: 12

So, the name segment of the string can vary between 2 or 3 characters, and the following digits always follow the same format `yyyymmdd`. How can I write a regex that extracts this information?

Comment: I bet r'(\D+)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})' would do the trick, but you can count on Wiktor to give you a certified working answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import re

strings_list = ['FWI20010112','DC20030405']
print(re.sub(r'(\w*)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})',r'name: \1, year: \2, month: \3, day: \4','\n'.join(strings_list)))
```

Output:

```py
name: FWI, year: 2001, month: 01, day: 12
name: DC, year: 2003, month: 04, day: 05
```